# Combining Collections With Gremlin Query

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop

Hi I am new to Tinkerpop and Gremlin and I am struggling with a traversal I am trying to perform.

Basically I have a set of vertex ids which I want to traverse from and find a set of vertices from certain out edges.  I want to associate the vertices following the out edges with the veracity it came from.  For example: 

`v1 -> e1 -> v2
v1 -> e2 -> v4
v3 -> e3 -> v5
v3 -> e4 -> v6`

So v1 has 2 out going edges (e1 and e2) to v2 and v4 and v3 has 2 out going edges (e3 and e4) to v5 and v6.  What I want is to get a result of a traversal that would look something like this
`[[[v1],[v2,v4]],[v3,[v5,v5]]]`

Can someone help me with a traversal using Gremlin that would help me get that result?  The closest I have come is with something like this
`graph.traversal().V(4264,40964144).as('people').map{it.get().vertices(OUT, 'codes_in')}.as('languages').union(select('people'), select('languages'))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way you can do it demonstrated with the "modern" [toy graph](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/3.1.1-incubating/tutorials/the-gremlin-console/#toy-graphs):

```
gremlin> graph = TinkerFactory.createModern()
==>tinkergraph[vertices:6 edges:6]
gremlin> g = graph.traversal()
==>graphtraversalsource[tinkergraph[vertices:6 edges:6], standard]
gremlin> g.V(1,4).group().by().by(out().fold())
==>[v[1]:[v[3], v[2], v[4]], v[4]:[v[5], v[3]]]
```

It just uses [group()](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/3.1.1-incubating/reference/#group-step). The first `by()` modulator represents the key of each group (in this case the start vertex) and then the second `by()` modulator is what you want in your group (in this case the `out()` vertex). Note that you must include `fold()` in the second `by()` to force iterate that internal traversal.

By the way, doing `graph.traversal()` is not a good pattern. Create the `TraversalSource` once and re-use it.

Comment: Thanks Stephen, that did the trick.  Much easier than I was anticipating!

Comment: Actually Stephen, I have one addition question.  I would like the properties of v1 and v3 included in the result as well.  I don't see that happening with the query you supplied.

Comment: I think I figured out a query that works
`graph.traversal().V(4264,40964144).group().by().by(union(fold(), out()).fold())`